# How to remove a user defined class object from PriorityQueue in JAVA

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue

I have a PriorityQueue of type node(user defined) which looks like this.
`PriorityQueue<node> pq = new PriorityQueue<node>();`

The node class contains two members. `int val` and `long cost`
Now is there a way to remove an object which exactly matches a particular val and cost values?
Something like this,
`pq.remove(new node(4, 1976))`
Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: You've tagged the question with comparator, so are your Node classes comparable? Can you show the remove code?

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Yes my node classes are comparable.

Comment: When your `node` class has a correct `equals` method based on `val` and `cost`, you can remove a matching element exactly as you have written, `pq.remove(new node(4, 1976))`.